# Yii2 application git ignore web/index and local configuration

Tags: php, git, yii2

I generate a Yii2 Application then initialized git and commit my change but `web/index.php` files are in gitignore and not pushed to the repo

Can I knew why and how to regenerate it if I cloned the project again from the remote repo?

Comment: You may want to copy it from [here](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-app-basic/blob/master/web/index.php), remove it from .gitignore and commit and push it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By framework design they are in `.gitignore`, that means you should not modify them at all.

Pretty much all changes that you want to do there can be done through [BootstrapInterface](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-bootstrapinterface.html).

By default `index.php` and some other files don't exist, they will appear only after running `init` command.

You should run it with different options on development and production environment (`0` for dev and `1` for prod).

But if for some reason you need to modify it and track with Git, you can always remove it from `.gitignore` (it's also adviced by @robsch in comment).